# Test case for login result using python in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writing a sample test case to display the login result of the page - http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login

When I run the test case, all the test cases pass and none of the logins are rejected. Here is my code -

```
for r in range(2,row+1):
    uname=utils.readData(path,'new',r,1)
    password=utils.readData(path,'new',r,2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='usr']").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='case_login']/form/input[3]").click()

    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'ACCESS DENIED!')]"):
        print("fail")
    else: print("Pass")

        utils.writeData(path,'new',r,3,"Test Fail")
```

utils is my module to read the data stored in the excel file.
Please tell me what I did wrong in this code, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not setting the username and password properly. You also need to search for the text in an h3 tag since the search text always appears in the main page. Also use find_elements_by_xpath (plural) when searching for text to prevent exceptions.

This code worked for me:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
target_url = 'http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login'
driver.get(target_url)

uname="admin"
password="12345"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='usr']").send_keys(uname)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pwd']").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='case_login']/form/input[3]").click()

if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[contains(text(), 'WELCOME')]")):
    print("Pass")
else: 
    print("Fail")
```